# printf padding from left by number other that zero

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have `a=10` var that I want to pad from left with integer 1 with 5 padding.

Output should be below:

```
11110
```

when Im doing:

```
printf "%05d\n" "${a}"
```

it gives me `00010`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per bash [printf](https://ss64.com/bash/printf.html) man page, it supports only zero padding, so you can't directly use integer padding other than zero.

You can do by string printing or pad by manipulating

```
a=10
printf '%s\n' 111${a}
```

or

```
 printf "% 5d\n" "10" | tr ' ' '1'
```

Comment: every suggestion works great.   I assume tr means translate.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just:

```
printf "% 5d\n" "10" | tr ' ' '1'
```

fill with spaces and then substitute spaces for ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this instruction:

```
printf "%5d" "$a" | sed 's/ /1/g'
```

It outputs:

```
11110
```